# separating out numbers in Reg_exp (Oracle)

Tags: regex, oracle

I have tried different variations on this query to no avail. To give context the numbers below are examples for contractions during labor. I am looking to parse out the first number and the 2nd if available- What I have so far below-I have it posted in the comments what I do & do not want.
Essentially ID 1-3 parsed into separate numbers
First number in ID 4 & 5-

Thank you in advance

```
with test as
(select 1 as ID,'2-4' as MEAS_VALUE from dual union all --want 2 & 4
 select 2 as ID,'2.5-4' as MEAS_VALUE from dual union all --want 2.5  & 4
 select 3 as ID,'2-4.5' as MEAS_VALUE from dual union all --want 2 & 4.5
 select 4 as ID,'x2' as MEAS_VALUE from dual union all --want x2
 select 5 as ID,'2 in 20 minutes' as MEAS_VALUE from dual) --want 2 but not  20
 select test.*,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'\d+.?([^-]\d)',1,1) as num1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(MEAS_VALUE,'\d+',1,2) as num2
from test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Question says:

> I am looking to parse out the first number and the 2nd if available

If so, then:

```
SQL> with test as
  2  (select 1 as ID,'2-4' as MEAS_VALUE from dual union all --want 2 & 4
  3   select 2 as ID,'2.5-4' as MEAS_VALUE from dual union all --want 2.5  & 4
  4   select 3 as ID,'2-4.5' as MEAS_VALUE from dual union all --want 2 & 4.5
  5   select 4 as ID,'x2' as MEAS_VALUE from dual union all --want x2
  6   select 5 as ID,'2 in 20 minutes' as MEAS_VALUE from dual) --want 2 but not  20
  7  select test.*,
  8    regexp_substr(meas_value, '\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 1) num1,
  9    regexp_substr(meas_value, '\d+(\.\d+)?', 1, 2) num2
 10  from test;

        ID MEAS_VALUE      NUM1       NUM2
---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
         1 2-4             2          4
         2 2.5-4           2.5        4
         3 2-4.5           2          4.5
         4 x2              2
         5 2 in 20 minutes 2          20

SQL>
```

There's no rule that explains desired output for IDs 4 (`x2`; why `x`? It is not a digit) and 5 (no `20`; why not? It is the 2nd digit here).

Comment: @littlefoot- Thank you. I do not want the X in line 4 as it needs to be converted to a number. As to the 20 in line 5, it's not an actual  measurement and hence should be excluded if that helps.

Comment: You're welcome. How is SQL supposed to know that "20 is not an actual measurement" (as opposed to e.g. 4.5 in line #3)?

Comment: -SQL doesn't-so with your syntax I changed it to -regexp_substr(meas_value, '\d+[^-](\d+)?', 1, 1) -boom.

Comment: If you managed to do it, great!